# innerHTML always returns 'undefine' in javaScript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I have one table in HTML and what I am trying to do is to find second column inside of it and get it's values into a string array.

Later I want to do simple if check and see if the value I have entered in one text box already exists in that array. But I keep getting 'undefine' both when I try to get .innerHTML for text box or .innerHTML for array element. I have tried with .value and .innerText as well, but I was getting same result.

I only can use plain javaScript, so no jQuery or other libraries. What I am missing here?

Here is my HTML for table:

```
<table id="results" width="360" border="1">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col" width="120">Date Created</th>
        <th scope="col" width="120">Name</th>
        <th scope="col" width="120">Tests</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr/>
      <td>07/08/2015</td>
      <td>Test Name</td>
      <td>Raven</td>
      </tr>
      <tr/>
      <td>01/08/2017</td>
      <td>Test Name 2</td>
      <td>PCT</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

This is HTML for text box:

```
  <form name="formTestInfo" method="post">
    Name:<br>
    <input type="text" id="tbName" name="tbName">
    <p id="nameVal"></p>
  </form>
```

And this is my script code:

```
 var secondCell = document.querySelectorAll('td:nth-child(2)');
 var cellValues = [];
 secondCell.forEach(function(singleCell) {
 cellValues.push(singleCell.innerText);
 });

 for(var i=0; i < cellValues.length ; i++)
 {
     if(document.getElementById("nameVal").innerHTML == cellValues[i].innerHTML)
     {
        var nameVal = "Name already exists in table!";
        validation = false;
     }
 }
```

I never get inside if because values are never find, but array is filled in with correct values. Somebody sees what is wrong here?

Comment: I see no table cells in your example with any IDs.

Comment: you are pushing text string in cellValues array so you should not use innerHTML on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
var secondCell = document.querySelectorAll('td:nth-child(2)');
var cellValues = [];
secondCell.forEach(function(singleCell) {
cellValues.push(singleCell.innerText);
});

for(var i=0; i < cellValues.length ; i++)
{
    if(document.getElementById("tbName").value == cellValues[i])
    {
      var nameVal = "Name already exists in table!";
      validation = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have pushed text string in cellValues array

```
cellValues.push(singleCell.innerText);
```

So you should use

```
document.getElementById("nameVal").innerHTML == cellValues[i]
```

to check if the name has already in exists in table.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var secondCell = document.querySelectorAll('td:nth-child(2)');
var nameInput = document.getElementById('tbName');
var cellValues = [];

var validation = true;
var error = "";

secondCell.forEach(function(singleCell) {
  cellValues.push(singleCell.innerText);
});

function testNameInput() {
  for(var i=0; i < cellValues.length ; i++){
    if(this.value == cellValues[i]){
      error = "Name already exists in table!";
      validation = false;
      break;
    }
  }
  if(error){
    alert(error);
    // this.value = ""; // or something
  }
}


nameInput.addEventListener("input", testNameInput);
```

```html
<table id="results" width="360" border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col" width="120">Date Created</th>
      <th scope="col" width="120">Name</th>
      <th scope="col" width="120">Tests</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>07/08/2015</td>
      <td>Foo</td>
      <td>Raven</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>01/08/2017</td>
      <td>Bar</td>
      <td>PCT</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table> 

<form name="formTestInfo" method="post">
  Name:<br>
  (Try with Foo or Bar)<br>
  <input type="text" id="tbName" name="tbName">
  <p id="nameVal"></p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you are retrieving `innerHTML` of normal string which is never going to work.

Second you are not comparing with value of the `input` but with the `innerHTML` of `<p id="nameVal">` in the line below.

```
if(document.getElementById("nameVal").innerHTML == cellValues[i].innerHTML)
```

```js
var secondCell = document.querySelectorAll('td:nth-child(2)');
 var cellValues = [];
 secondCell.forEach(function(singleCell) {
     cellValues.push(singleCell.innerText);   
 });

function validate(){
     for(var i=0; i < cellValues.length ; i++){
         if(document.getElementById("tbName").value == cellValues[i]){
            document.getElementById("nameVal").innerHTML = "Name already exists in table!";
            validation = false;
         }
      }
 }
```

```html
<table id="results" width="360" border="1">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col" width="120">Date Created</th>
        <th scope="col" width="120">Name</th>
        <th scope="col" width="120">Tests</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr/>
      <td>07/08/2015</td>
      <td>Test Name</td>
      <td>Raven</td>
      </tr>
      <tr/>
      <td>01/08/2017</td>
      <td>Test Name 2</td>
      <td>PCT</td>
      </tr>
    </thttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/38891283/innerhtml-always-returns-undefine-in-javascript#body>
  </table>
<form name="formTestInfo" method="post">
    Name:<br>
    <input type="text" id="tbName" name="tbName">
    <p id="nameVal"></p>
  </form>
<input type="button" value="Validate" onclick="validate()">
```